# Writing the Terminal displayed output in a file

Tags: linux, pipe, pipeline

I'm trying to write the terminal displayed output in a file. Is there any **pipe command** to run the following two command at the same time **but sequentially. So basically first it will run the first command and result of first command will be used in by second command.** Now I'm running commands one after another.

```
python test_1_result.py > result_1.txt
python test_2_result.py > result_2.txt
```

Thanks in advance for any suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean you want to write the results into the same file? One after the other? Then use `>>` instead of `>`. The `>>` operator appends to a file instead of overwriting the complete content like `>` does.

In your case, the commands would be like this:

```
python test_1_result.py >> result.txt
python test_2_result.py >> result.txt
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion but I want both command will run in one line but sequentially basically python test_2_result.py > result_2.txt will be run after first command execution. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to run both commands at the same time (where each process writes to a different file), just put the first command in the background:

```
python test_1_result.py > result_1.txt &
python test_2_result.py > result_2.txt
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion but I want both command will run in one line but sequentially basically python test_2_result.py > result_2.txt will be run after first command execution. Sorry for the confusion .

Answer (score 0):

Simply at a semicolon (how I think it's called) between the two commands.

```
python test_1_result.py > result_1.txt ; python test_2_result.py > result_2.txt
```